# Подключение Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library

В build.gradle проекта или модуля нужно подключать библиотеку? Если в файл проекта, то выдает ошибку

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

если в файл модуля, то ошибок нет, но библиотеку не видит.

app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.ucoz.softoad.sudoku"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'

}
```

Project:

```
/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Проблема с библиотекой com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Смотря где Вам нужно использовать библиотеку: если во всём проекте - подключайте в build.gradle проекта, если только в одном модуле - подключайте в build.gradle модуля.

Судя по вашему build.gradle файлу, вам нужно заменить `compile` на `implementation` - в этом у вас ошибка. [Ключевое слово `compile` было объявлено устаревшим](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) и его следует заменять `implementation` либо `api`.

Comment: @alex, Вы заменили все три последних compile в блоке dependencies?

Comment: Проблема только с библиотекой для GridLAyout. Пробовал, как Вы сказали, но проблема осталась прежней. В градле проекта выдает ошибку, а если прописать в градле модуля синхронизация проходит. Ставлю минимальную версию проекта api 13. GridLAyout в макете сразу подчеркивается красным, то есть библиотеку, как я понимаю, не видит.

Comment: @alex, а если минимальную версию проекта сделать 27, проект собирается?

Comment: нет. только если в  dependencies build.gradle проекта я ничего не добавляю

Comment: в логе просит установить 

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager. Но он установлен

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что библиотека видна из модуля. Просто я по не опытности неправильно к ней обращался из xml