# Ошибка при компиляции проекта после обновления Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Обновил Android Studio. Теперь всплывает вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Помимо скриншота, не помешает добавить хотя бы одно сообщение из Java compiler в тело вопроса (копипастом). Это поможет проиндекстировать вопрос в поисковиках, и если на него дадут хороший ответ, другие смогут найти его не создавая новый вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768761/177345